# OpenGL(in Qt ) - problem in rotation

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl

I made a simple code in openGL. You have to select a picture, that's it. Now you can make the rotation by using these keys

- a,s -> rotate about x axis
- d,f -> rotate about y axis
- b,n -> rotate about z axis.

The problem is z-Axis rotation works fine always. But, the x,y rotations are not always correct.

**Test:**
    press any (one) button, then you can see one axis is not at all moving, the other axis are moving. You can check this for the all three axises. But after some time, even though you tried to rotate the object about x axis, you can see that all the three axises are moving. The strange thing is, rotation about z axis is always working properly. only the other two are making the headache.

Here is the "main.cpp"

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include <QVector3D>
#include <QWidget>

class MyMessageBox:public QMessageBox
{
public:
    MyMessageBox(std::string message,QWidget *parent=0):QMessageBox(QMessageBox::NoIcon,QString("ErrorMessage"),QString(message.c_str()),QMessageBox::Ok,parent,Qt::Widget)
    {
    }
};

class MyOpenGL:public QGLWidget
{
    double x_Rot;
    double y_Rot;
    double z_Rot;
    QVector<GLuint *> textures;  // it does nothing. It got added just for the sake of the program run
    QVector<QImage> openGL_Images;
public:
    MyOpenGL(QWidget * parent);
    ~MyOpenGL();
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();
    void drawCube(QPoint upper_Left_Point,int length,int width,int height,QVector<GLuint *> textures);
    void drawAxis();
    QVector3D get_In_OpenGL_Coordinates(QPoint qwidget_Point);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
};

MyOpenGL::MyOpenGL(QWidget *parent):QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers),parent)
{
    setAutoFillBackground(false);
}

MyOpenGL::~MyOpenGL()
{

}

void MyOpenGL::initializeGL()
{
    //textures.push_back(new GLuint);
    //textures.push_back(new GLuint);

    QString fileName=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
    openGL_Images.push_back(convertToGLFormat(QImage(fileName).scaled(QSize(256,256))));
    openGL_Images.push_back(convertToGLFormat(QImage(fileName).scaled(QSize(256,256))));
    openGL_Images.push_back(convertToGLFormat(QImage(fileName).scaled(QSize(256,256))));
    openGL_Images.push_back(convertToGLFormat(QImage(fileName).scaled(QSize(256,256))));
    openGL_Images.push_back(convertToGLFormat(QImage(fileName).scaled(QSize(256,256))));
    openGL_Images.push_back(convertToGLFormat(QImage(fileName).scaled(QSize(256,256))));

    //glGenTextures(1,textures[0]);
    //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,*textures[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
}

void MyOpenGL::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(45,0,w,h);
    gluPerspective(45.0f,((double)width())/height(),1.0f,100.0f);
    //gluOrtho2D(-10.0f,10.0f,-10.0f,10.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    paintGL();
}

void MyOpenGL::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10.0);
    glRotatef(x_Rot,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(y_Rot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(z_Rot,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

    drawAxis();

    //drawCube(QPoint(0,0),1,1,1,textures);
}

void MyOpenGL::drawCube(QPoint upper_Left_Back_Point, int length, int width, int height,QVector<GLuint *> textures1)
{
    //glGenTextures(1,textures[0]);
    //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,*textures[0]);

    QVector3D starting_Point = get_In_OpenGL_Coordinates(upper_Left_Back_Point);

    double x=starting_Point.x();
    double y=starting_Point.y();
    double z=starting_Point.z();

    //glGenTextures(1,textures[0]);
    //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,*textures[0]);

     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,openGL_Images[0].width(),openGL_Images[0].height(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,openGL_Images[0].bits());
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
//   glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
     glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex3f(x-width,y+height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex3f(x+width,y+height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(x+width,y+height,z+length);
     glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex3f(x-width,y+height,z+length);
     glEnd();

     //glGenTextures(1,textures[1]);
     //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,*textures[1]);
     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,openGL_Images[1].width(),openGL_Images[1].height(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,openGL_Images[1].bits());
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     //glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
     glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex3f(x+width,y+height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex3f(x+width,y-height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(x+width,y-height,z+length);
     glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex3f(x+width,y+height,z+length);
     glEnd();

     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,openGL_Images[2].width(),openGL_Images[2].height(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,openGL_Images[2].bits());
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     //glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
     glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex3f(x+width,y-height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex3f(x-width,y-height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(x-width,y-height,z+length);
     glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex3f(x+width,y-height,z+length);
     glEnd();


     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,openGL_Images[3].width(),openGL_Images[3].height(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,openGL_Images[3].bits());
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     //glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
     glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex3f(x-width,y+height,z+length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex3f(x-width,y+height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(x-width,y-height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex3f(x-width,y-height,z+length);
     glEnd();

     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,openGL_Images[4].width(),openGL_Images[4].height(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,openGL_Images[4].bits());
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     //glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
     glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex3f(x-width,y+height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex3f(x+width,y+height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(x+width,y-height,z-length);
     glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex3f(x-width,y-height,z-length);
     glEnd();

     glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,openGL_Images[5].width(),openGL_Images[5].height(),0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,openGL_Images[5].bits());
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     //glColor3f(0,1,1);
     glTexCoord2f(0,1);glVertex3f(x-width,y+height,z+length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,1);glVertex3f(x+width,y+height,z+length);
     glTexCoord2f(1,0);glVertex3f(x+width,y-height,z+length);
     glTexCoord2f(0,0);glVertex3f(x-width,y-height,z+length);
     glEnd();
}

void MyOpenGL::drawAxis()
{
    //int length = 1;
    //int height = 1;
    //int width = 1;

    //int x = 0;
    //int y=0;
    //int z = 0;


    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(3,0,0);

    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(0,3,0);

    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(0,0,3);
    //glVertex3f(x-width,y+height,z+length);
    //glVertex3f(x+width,y+height,z+length);
    //glVertex3f(x+width,y-height,z+length);
    //glVertex3f(x-width,y-height,z+length);
    glEnd();
}

QVector3D MyOpenGL::get_In_OpenGL_Coordinates(QPoint qwidget_Point)
{
    return QVector3D(0,0,0);
}

void MyOpenGL::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
        case Qt::Key_A:
            x_Rot-=5;
            break;
        case Qt::Key_S:
            x_Rot+=5;
            break;
        case Qt::Key_D:
            y_Rot+=5;
            break;
        case Qt::Key_F:
            y_Rot-=5;
            break;
        case Qt::Key_B:
            z_Rot+=5;
            break;
        case Qt::Key_N:
            z_Rot-=5;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    updateGL();
}

void MyOpenGL::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    double x = event->pos().x();
    double y = event->pos().y();
    double z=-1;

    glReadPixels(x,y,1,1,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,&z);

    double projection[16];
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,projection);
    double modelView[16];
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,modelView);

    int viewPort[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,viewPort);

    double x_Gl;
    double y_Gl;
    double z_Gl;
    gluUnProject(x,y,z,modelView,projection,viewPort,&x_Gl,&y_Gl,&z_Gl);

    QString ss;
    QTextStream ss_Text(&ss);
    ss_Text << x_Gl << " " << y_Gl << " " << z_Gl ;
    MyMessageBox mm(ss.toStdString());
    mm.exec();
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    MyOpenGL * f = new MyOpenGL(NULL);
    f->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here , the .pro file

```
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

QT += opengl
```

Somebody please help me out of this.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Mikola I am expecting the z-Axis's behaviour in other two axises.

Comment: I am sorry, that is not very specific.  What do you mean by "the z-Axis behavior"?

Comment: @Mikola The above app code just draws three axes. When I rotate the axes about one axis, then one should stay, and the other two have to rotate around it. But, in the above code, all the three axises are rotating. It perfectly works as I expected, when the rotation is about z-Axis.

Comment: Ok, what it sounds like you are describing is that you want to apply the rotations incrementally.  Because rotations in 3D do not commute, you can't just sum up all the x,y,z rotations independently.  If you want this behavior, you will need to accumulate all of the rotations in a matrix/quaternion on the client side; then rotate by that amount before drawing.  The links in my answer should help.

Answer (score 4):

First some observations on your code:

1. Where do you initialize x_Rot, y_Rot and z_Rot?  I don't see where this is happening.

Next, some more general comments:

Technically, what you are doing now is rotating about x,y and z.  If you want to do something else, like for example rotate incrementally with each button press, then you need to think carefully about what you are trying to do.  One way to do it is to apply the rotation matrices in OpenGL incrementally.  Another possibility is to store a quaterion/matrix on the client and then each frame reset the view transformation.  Still another possibility is to bash out a bunch of trig and compute the correct deviation in the x/y/z angles per rotation (not recommended).  You can do any one of these things and more, once you understand what it is you are actually trying to do.  To get to this point, you will have to read a bit (sorry, that is just how math works).  As a starting point, here are some basic wiki pages to help get you going:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_representation_%28mathematics%29

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Answer (score 1):

It seem that your problem is [Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)

Using quaternions is one of the easiest ways to deal with this problem.

Comment: +1 for Gimbal Lock. Note that just storing the rotation in a matrix each frame, and update that continuously will probably solve the problem. Quaternions are good for interpolating rotations, but not always necessary when you just want to rotate something incrementally.